# Função contrária ao TRIM

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Como inserir caracteres em um campo `varchar` no MySQL?

Por exemplo, no update com trim vc pode remover certos caracteres de um campo `varchar`... mas e adicionar ?

Exemplo: `update tabela set campo = TRIM(leading '11' from campo);`

Comment: Adicionar um caracter onde? no inicio no fim ou em qualquer posição?

Comment: Quero adicionar no início, mas se puder adicionar em qualquer posição eu vou gostar de aprender !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O MySQL tem a função `concat()` para concatenar strings como ela pode receber `N` argumentos você pode colocar qualquer coisa no inicio e no final.

```
update tabela set campo = concat('inicio ', campo, ' fim') where id = ?
```

Comment: Muito obrigada !

Answer (score 9):

O contrário de fazer um *trimming* (aparando) é fazer um *padding* (preenchendo), então as funções a serem usadas devem ser [`PADL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) e [`PADR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, obrigada !

Answer (score -2):

Pode usar o operador || (concatenação de string):

`select 'Hello' || ' ' || 'World';` retorna `Hello World`.

Comment: Não funciona pra `UPDATE`, o campo fica como `0` e tanto no terminal quanto no PHP isto `select 'Hello' || ' ' || 'World';` retorna `0` também. Ou seja não fez a concatenação em mysql.

Comment: Oi, Jose. Note as tags embaixo da pergunta, o DB é mysql. Neste caso, o `||` não serve. O `||` em mysql é o OR para valores booleanos, e o `|` o OR para valores numéricos.